# The intransitive usage of "satisfy"

Tags: word-usage, transitivity, intransitive-verbs

I lighted upon a sentence in [the New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/03/16/dining/drinks/review-blended-scotch.html):

> Actually almost any tidbit — notably pigs in blankets — that the bar sends my way will **satisfy**.

This usage of *satisfy* strikes me as uncommon, if not jarring, as the verb *satisfy* almost always occurs as a transitive verb. I have just checked all the major online dictionaries. The Oxford Dictionaries Online explicitly says it should be used **"with object"**, while some others have "intransitive verb" listed but no example sentences. I can't seem to find one instance in contemporary texts that uses *satisfy* intransitively.

So is this usage archaic? Or has it never been a common/widely accepted usage? What is the currency of this usage?

Comment: I feel like I hear it in advertisements all the time.

Comment: @Mitch Then does it mean it is a new usage and hasn't entered every dictionary? Some examples would be helpful.

Comment: @L.Moneta The OED has a passage from 1600 using it intransitively. Added to Zebrafish's answer.

Comment: Use of a verb that is normally transitive without an object is often fine, but may confuse [a person].

Comment: Completely unrelated to advertising, this is totally and completely normal in English, @L.Moneta. It is not archaic, it is not unusual, it is completely normal and current.

Comment: (Its true that (in most countries) whenever you say "really satisfies", you think of the Snickers slogan.  But so what?  Any time any English speaker says "Yesterday" they think of the Beatles song.  This is a completely commonplace phenomenon in English.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Popularly, this use of "satisfy" is seen in the Snickers slogan: [Packed with peanuts, Snickers really satisfies](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ll9pIcOsBE0)
At least since 1986.

I always heard the advertising slogan simply as "Snickers really satisfies."

> v.i.
>   10. to give satisfaction
>  [Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/satisfy)
>
> v.intr.
>   1. To be sufficient or adequate.
>   2. To give satisfaction.
>  [American Heritage Dictionary](http://American%20Heritage%20Dictionary)
>
> verb (used without object), satisfied, satisfying.
>   10.
>  to give satisfaction
>  [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/satisfy)
>
> intransitive verb : to be adequate : suffice; also : please
>   [Merriam-Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/satisfy)

And lastly from the OED with quotes starting 1600. My thanks to Mitch for adding these to my answer:

> 5.absol. and intr. 
>   To cause or give satisfaction or contentment.
>
> 1600   Chester Pl. Proëm 44   
>   If the same be likeinge to the comons all, then our desier is to satisfie—for that is all our game.
>
> 1649   J. Winthrop Hist. New Eng. (1825) (modernized text) I. 210   
>   This would not satisfy, but they called him to answer publickly.
>
> 1831   Westm. Rev. Jan. 243   
>   What would have satisfied from the Duke will not satisfy from Lord Grey.
>
> 1836   R. W. Emerson Nature iii, in Wks. (1906) II. 145   
>   But in other hours, Nature satisfies by its loveliness, and without any mixture of corporeal benefit.
>
> 1903   Heart of Heretic vi. 33   
>   The first and last need of an aspect of religious truth is that it shall satisfy.

Comment: Zebrafish, I added the OED. Please re-edit as you see fit.

Comment: @Mitch That's very kind, thank you. How did you find these? The only way I tried was by searching for "satisfy." or "satisfies.", specifically for end of sentence positions, but Google search kept returning results ignoring the full stop.

Answer (score 3):

American Heritage has two meanings listed for the [intransitive form](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/satisfy):

> 1. To be sufficient or adequate.
> 2. To give satisfaction.

The first is similar to *suffice* and the second is a little bit like *suit*.